# How to trigger only one button with vuedraggable?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vuedraggable, v-data-table

I am implementing table draggable with vue. However, what I want is to trigger only the column button on the v-icon, but when all the rows are pressed, all triggers. How can I limit the draggable to only certain columns?

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    loading-text="편성 리스트가 없습니다"
    :loading="loadingToggle"
    item-key="id"
    :items="adList"
    :hide-default-footer="true"
>
    <template v-slot:body="props">
        <draggable :list="props.items" tag="tbody">
            <tr v-for="(item, idx) in props.items" :key="idx">
                <td><v-icon>mdi-menu</v-icon></td>
                <td>{{ idx + 1 }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Sid }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.companySid }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.companyName }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.gnName }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.Slot }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.StartDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.EndDate }}</td>
                <td>{{ item.StatusName }}</td>
            </tr>
        </draggable>
    </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question: do you want to drag the **whole** row by dragging **only icon**, or do you want to drag **only icons** from one row to another?

Comment: @dreamwalker I want to drag the whole row by dragging only icon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Vue.Draggable handles](https://sortablejs.github.io/Vue.Draggable/#/handle).

You can just specify `handle` attribute in `<draggable>` tag with some CSS class, and then apply this CSS class to your `<v-icon>` or `<td>` tag.

It's possible to create more than one handle.

So your code should be like:

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  loading-text="편성 리스트가 없습니다"
  :loading="loadingToggle"
  item-key="id"
  :items="adList"
  :hide-default-footer="true"
>
  <template v-slot:body="props">
    <draggable :list="props.items" tag="tbody" handle=".handle">
      <tr v-for="(item, idx) in props.items" :key="idx">
        <td><v-icon class="handle">mdi-menu</v-icon></td> <!-- first handle -->
        <td>{{ idx + 1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.Sid }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.companySid }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.companyName }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.gnName }}</td>
        <td class="handle">{{ item.Slot }}</td> <!-- second handle -->
        <td>{{ item.StartDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.EndDate }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.StatusName }}</td>
      </tr>
    </draggable>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Do not forget that by default `v-data-table` component prevents you from reordering rows.

Since you didn't mention this problem in the question, I hope you've already solved it. But if not, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64272787/9275224) or [this discussion in issue](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/2234) should help you.